# Indexing an entire MongoDB collection into Elastcticsearch quickly

Tags: c#, mongodb, elasticsearch, indexing

I have a collection in MongoDB which I am indexing into Elasticsearch. I am doing this in a C# process. The collection has 100 million documents, and for each document, I have to query other documents in order to denormalise into the Elasticsearch index.

This all takes time. Reading from MongoDB is the slow part (indexing is relatively quick). I am batching the data from MongoDB as efficiently as I can but the process takes over 2 days.

This only has to happen when the mapping in Elasticsearch changes, but that has happened a couple of times over the last month.
Are there any ways of improving the performance for this?

Comment: Are you already importing this data to Elasticsearch through the `_bulk` API?

Comment: Is I'm right, you import some data from mongo to elasticsearch. Then, when you need change elasticsearch mappings, you delete old data and launch import into new elasticsearch index with updated mappings?

Comment: @BrunoHenrique It's not using the bulk API, but it is not really the indexing that is slow - it is reading from MongoDB.

Comment: @froosty That is correct. If the mapping has changed, the only thing to do is to delete the index and re-index the documents. At least that is my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need launch import from scratch (I mean import from MongoDB), when you change mappings. Read this: [Elasticsearch Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docs-reindex.html)

When you need to change mapping you must:

1. Create new index with new mapping
2. Reindex data from the old index into a new index using the built-in feature of elasticsearch.

After this old documents will be indexed with new mappings inside the new index. And built-in reindex in elasticsearch will work more quickly, than import from MongoDB via HTTP API.

If you will use reindex, don't forget to use parameter `wait_for_completion`(this parameter described in the documentation). This will run the reindex in the background.

Is this approach will solve your problem?